# how to make the min-height of body equal to screen.height

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, css

[My Website](http://shayonainfo.com) here I have a page [About Us](http://shayonainfo.com/aboutShayona) due to lack of content we can not cover the complete height of the screen. And my footer starts floating in the air.. I tried doing it using min-height in a fieldset but unfortunately it works on my browser only as soon as I change my browser or try on other system the problem start again...
I have tried:
**CSS**

```
html,body{  
min-height:100%;  
height:100%;  
}  
[id]center_wrapper{  
min-height:100%;  
height:100%; 
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var body1 = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];  
console.log(body1);  
body1.style.minHeight = screen.height;  
body1.style.height = screen.height;  
console.log(body1.style.minHeight);
```

**jQuery**

```
$('body').css('min-height', screen.height);  
$('body').css('height', screen.height);  
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.minHeight);
```

While using both jQuery and javascript Console Log it does shows 704px but it is not 704px.. I `guess` it might be because change occurs after DOM is created..

Any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made it..
What I did is:
**1.** Got the offset() and height() of the div I wanted to be at the bottom
**2.** Got the window height()
**3.** Finally using jQuery css property I got the margin necessary to keep it down

The Code is as:

```
$(function () {
        var x = $('#footer-info').offset();
        var z = $(window).height();
        var y = $('#footer-info').height();
        console.log(y);
        if (z > x.top) {
            var res = z - x.top - y;
            console.log(res);
            $('#footer-info').css('margin-top', res);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you've already incorporated this on your site I just wanted to let you know it doesn't work on firefox, still looks the same to me.

Answer (score 5):

Thought I'd add an answer as I was searching for a solution to this problem and found one [here](http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/), no javascript needed.

Code taken from the linked article:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The HTML is basic with a wrapper directly inside the body.

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#5ee;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

The key points of the CSS is the wrapper's min-height:100% and the footer being absolutely positioned at the bottom inside it. You need to make sure the html and body elements are styled as specified as well, and give the content some space at the bottom as the footer will cover it.

The footer will stick to the bottom of the window with short content but be pushed beyond it with larger content.

Comment: Why not use `header` and `footer` tags rather than a generic div with id?

Comment: Well, _I_ would.  Like I said though, I copied the code from the link I gave.

Answer (score 1):

> **From my point of view this is a process flow for your problem.**

**1. GET SCREEN HEIGHT.**

```
var docheight = $(document).height();
alert(docheight);
```

**2. THEN GET TAB MARGIN FROM TOP OF SCREEN BY USING.**

```
var offset = $(this).offset();
var mydivlft = offset.left;   // for LEFT margin from screen
var mydivtop = offset.top;   // for TOP margin from screen
alert(mydivtop);
```

**3. GET YOUR FOOTER HEIGHT BY USING ITs ID / CLASS.**

```
var footerheight = $('#footer-info').height();
alert(footerheight);
```

**4. NOW SET YOUR TAB VIEW HEIGHT**

```
YOUR TABVIEW_HEIGHT = SCREEN_HEIGHT (minus) FOOTER_HEIGHT (minus) TAB_MARGIN_FROM_TOP
```

**5. CODE**

```
var x = mydivtop+footerheight
var newheight = docheight-x;
```

**6. SET YOUR TAB VIEW HEIGHT**

```
$('#tabs div').height(newheight);
```

Comment: where do I put this code... **within $(document).ready()** won't work I guess..?

Comment: Thanks to @SandeepVirani for the Idea..!!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, since that didn't work... You have an html element style found in your div id "center_wrapper" it is contained within div id "title". Change the element style of min-height to 450 as shown below:

```
<fieldset id="center_wrapper" style="min-height: 450px;">
```

That should do the trick...

Comment: won't it change with browser and/or system..?  It didn't worked for my Mozilla.. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Since it's the bottom of the page, so long as it is always farther out then the end of the page it will render at the bottom.

Comment: @Bhavik I went ahead and updated it with something else... this should work across all platforms np. I didn't notice this one earlier as it is an HTML element style which was holding a value of 414px and wasn't in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want is the footer pinned to the bottom of the browser window. Give this a try:

```
#footer-info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: His other pages (Home, services, etc...) share the same footer and CSS. On those pages the content is larger and would therefore create a "moving" footer when scrolling up and down the page.